# java ssl connection refused, but it works on local machine

Tags: java, ssl, connection

I have a problem with my applications.
They connect thru SSL and it works on a local machine (on one computer), but when i put one application on another computer (in LAN) i see ConnectionException: Connection refused: connect

my server config (webservices with spring and jetty)

```xml
<httpj:connector>
    <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector">
        <property name="port" value="8456" />
        <property name="keystore" value="./config/server.jks" />
        <property name="password" value="server" />
        <property name="keyPassword" value="server" />

        <property name="truststore" value="./config/server-trust.jks" />
        <property name="trustPassword" value="server-trust" />
        <property name="needClientAuth" value="false" />
        <property name="wantClientAuth" value="true" />
```

my client config:

```
Ssl.TrustStore=conf/client-trust2.jks
Ssl.TrustStorePassword=client-trust
Ssl.TrustStoreType=jks
Ssl.KeyStore=conf/client2.jks
Ssl.KeyStorePassword=client
Ssl.KeyPassword=client2
Ssl.KeyStoreType=jks
```

keys are generated by me (java's keytool)

another strange thing is that during proxy creation (WS proxy)
I see that connection is made and WSDL is sent (i see that with `javax.net.debug=all`), but if i try to execute webmethod i've got `connection refused: connect`

is it some problem with SSL configuration ?

Comment: Any firewall on the way?

Comment: LAN is my private network (switch and two PCs)
i've created simple SSL server/client now for testing, and it works (on two computer thru LAN too, still using the same keys/certs)

i can connect my new simple client to a WS on spring/jetty on the same computer, but i can't connect if its on another.

so i'm guessing that the problem is with webservice server on jetty/spring

Answer (score 0):

SSL has nothing to do with it. You would get the same error with a plaintext socket. Try it. Either the host:port you specified is incorrect or an intervening firewall hasn't cooperated.

Comment: Or perhaps you're not listening on all interfaces